# How to print or echo ACF repeater fields of a taxonomy in single template?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is my code to echo ACF fields if a taxonomy

```
<?php   
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'agents' );                        
    $socials = get_field('ag_social', $terms);
    print_r($socials);        
    ?>
```

the result is this: `( [0] => Array ( [ag_telegram] => https://t.me/+xx [ag_whatsapp] => https://wa.me/xxx [ag_insta] => https://instagram.com/x ) )`

can anyone help me to print each field separately

```
for telegram ex: https://t.me/+xx
for whatsapp ex: https://wa.me/xxx
for instagram ex: https://instagram.com/x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**If you want it to be exactly like that, write this down.**

```
<?php   
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'agents' );                        
$socials = get_field('ag_social', $terms);
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo "For : " . ucfirst(substr($key, 3)) . " ex : " . $value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

---

**And if you just want to write links, write this down.**

```
<?php   
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'agents' );                        
$socials = get_field('ag_social', $terms);
foreach($array as $value){
    echo $value;
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for help Nashwan but the result prints Array word.